# Powerlines query in overpass turbo

Tags: openstreetmap, line, query, filter, overpass-api

I want to achieve following in overpass turbo:

1. Map/display transmission lines (`power=line`) and distribution lines (`power=minor_line`) of a specific area in map. I used below query but it doesn't correctly work (it only displays circles in map, not powerlines):

   ```
   area[name="Bonn"]->.a;

   (node[building](area.a);
     way[power=cable](area.a);
     rel[building](area.a);
   );
   out center;
   ```
2. My query should display powerlines in map as below figure.

[image]

Comment: You should use `out geom; `  instead of `out center;`

Comment: @mmd.Thank you for this.How can i display both  transmission lines `(power=line)` and distribution lines `(power=minor_line)` on a map. Is there a way to achieve this? Should i use boolean operators like: `"type:way & (power=line | power=cable | power=minor_line)`

Comment: Either add another `way[power=minor_line](area.a);` and `way[power=line](area.a);` right after `way[power=cable](area.a);` to your query, or use regular expressions. The boolean operator example you've mentioned in only valid for the overpass turbo wizard, this is not valid Overpass QL syntax.

Comment: i tried this query: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/Rdo .It doesnt displays transmission and distribution lines in different color. Only display single color. Actually i want to get the paths of these powerlines

Comment: overpass turbo has some MapCSS styling options. Read more about it here:https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo/MapCSS

Comment: Thank you once again. It's not about coloring and tick marks (styles). I just want to plot `transmission lines (power=line)` and `distribution lines (power=minor_line)` together in one map.